# Fiware Ultralight 2.0 IoTAgent: How to send measure from a device?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am working on a POC to create Smart City IoT project using Fiware platform. 
I am trying to run end to end flow.
I have following Docker containers running.

CONTAINER ID            PORTS       NAMES

24f036202f78        0.0.0.0:4041->4041/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7896->7896/tcp fiware_iotagent_1

81e16c78312e        0.0.0.0:1026->1026/tcp                       fiware_orion_1

bf699e1acdd3        0.0.0.0:1883->1883/tcp                    fiware_mosquitto_1

bfc256deddd0        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                      fiware_mongo_1

I am using following tutorials.

http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection-to-the-internet-of-things/how-to-read-measures-captured-from-iot-devices/

I am able to create Service and devices. (data is given below).

Now, when I am sending measurement it is not working.

Please guide me what am I doing wrong? And if possible provide reference having step by step example to run end to end IoT testing.

**Request Details (Using POSTMAN)
Header**

```
Content-Type:text/plain
fiware-service:{{FiwareService}}
fiware-servicepath:{{FiwareServicePath}}
X-Auth-Token:{{AuthToken}}
```

**POST URL:** http://130.206.XXX.XXX:4041/iot/d?k=tourguide-devices&i=restaurant-sensor-0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f

**Body Contents:**
't|25'

**Response:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /iot/d</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Service and Device Data with Header using IotAgent URL i.e.  http://130.206.XXX.XXX:4041/iot/**
**Header**

```
Content-Type:application/json
fiware-service:tourguide
fiware-servicepath:/
X-Auth-Token:{{AuthToken}}
```

**Service**

```
{
    "_id": "5a7063e6b8adcc0001c34723",
    "subservice": "/",
    "service": "tourguide",
    "apikey": "tourguide-devices",
    "resource": "/iot/dev-restaurants",
    "attributes": [],
    "lazy": [],
    "commands": [],
    "entity_type": "tourguide-devices",
    "internal_attributes": [],
    "static_attributes": []
}
```

**Device**

```
{
    "device_id": "restaurant-sensor-0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f",
    "service": "tourguide",
    "service_path": "/",
    "entity_name": "0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f",
    "entity_type": "Restaurant",
    "transport": "HTTP",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "object_id": "t",
            "name": "temperature",
            "type": "number"
        }
    ],
    "lazy": [],
    "commands": [],
    "static_attributes": [],
    "protocol": "UL20"
}
```

Regards,

Krishan Babbar

Answer (score 1):

I just followed "Fiware Tour Guide" from
http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiware-tour-guide-application-a-tutorial-on-how-to-integrate-the-main-fiware-ges/introduction/
 and everything seems working fine.

I was using port 4041 instead of port 7896. Below request is working fine.

http://MyIPHost:7896/iot/d?k=tourguide-devices-Franchise1&i=0115206c51f60b48b77e4c937835795c33bb953f-kitchen-temperature2

Data:

t|39

Regards,
Krishan

Comment: Even you can send multiple parameters as well.
p1|v1|p2|v2|p3|v3....

Regards, Krishan